# Signed apk installs on one device but fails on another

Tags: android

When I `adb install` my signed apk on one Android device, the installation goes fine. However, when I try to install it on another device, I get an `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES` error. Looking at the log messages coming from the device, I see the following information:

```
Exception reading AndroidManifest.xml in /data/app/vmdl-996512191.tmp
      java.lang.SecurityException: META-INF/MYSTUFF.SF has invalid digest for lib/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_shared.so in /data/app/vmdl-996512191.tmp
```

I have looked at other posts with such errors. Most mention that such errors occur if the apk file has not been signed properly. But I have tested the same apk on many other devices and the install goes through fine on all the devices.

Wondering if anyone has any insight on why it won't work on this specific device. Regards.

Comment: are you installing it in marshmallow?

Comment: I think it is about a 3rd party library you added to your project. If so probably you need to add armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86 version .so files.